# Strange behaviour of a System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, interlocked, interlocked-increment

I am trying to get some insight into how Timer will use thread pool. I wrote following simple snippet.

```
class Program
    {
        static private readonly Action Action = () => {
                                                     Thread.SpinWait(100 * 10000);
                                                     Interlocked.Increment(ref _data);
        };

        private static volatile int _data;

        static private Timer _threadCountChecker = new Timer(
            (obj) =>
                {
                    var t = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;
                    Console.WriteLine("Using {0} threads.", t.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine(Program._data);
                }, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var l = new List<Timer>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                l.Add(new Timer((obj) => Action(), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
            }

            var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            exitEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
```

Surprisingly this is the output I get:

> Using 14 threads. 10 Using 14 threads. 18 Using 14 threads. 28 Using
>   14 threads. 39 Using 14 threads. 48 Using 15 threads. 58 Using 15
>   threads. 69 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80 Using 15
>   threads. 80 Using 15 threads. 80

The data variable stays at 80 no matter for how long I keep running the process.

Does anyone have an idea why the variable gets updated for the first 8 iteration and just stops being incremented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timers got garbage collected.  Add this statement after the eventWait.WaitOne() call to fix that:

```
  GC.KeepAlive(l);
```

The way the GC treats local variables in the Release build is explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034).